# To implement Foursquare in my app

Tags: iphone

How to implement foursquare in my app.I have tried some sample app but I don't know how to do that exactly.can any one guide me.

Thanks....

Answer (score 2):

Following are the sample applications provided on github...

1. [anoopr / core-data-talk](https://github.com/anoopr/core-data-talk/tree/master/example)
2. [Constantine-Fry / Foursquare-API-v2](https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/Foursquare-API-v2)

Comment: I tried....I can get the nearby vebus but I couldn't checkin with this sample....

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/Foursquare-API-v2/tree/master/Foursquare2-iOS

Download this project and drag Foursquare2 folder in your project and json parser.

This what i did to get the near by places..

```
   [Foursquare2 searchVenuesNearByLatitude:lat_String 
                              longitude:log_String 
                                 accuracyLL:nil 
                                   altitude:nil 
                                accuracyAlt:nil 
                                      query:searchString
                                      limit:@"10" 
                                     intent:@"browse" 
                                 categoryId:nil
                                     Radius:radius
                                   callback:^(BOOL     success,id result){
                                       if (success) {
                                          //     NSLog(@"Result : %@",result);
                                           [self     parseplacesForSearch:result];
                                       }
                                       else {
                                               UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" 
                                                                                                  message:@"Sorry!! their is no places around your location" 
                                                                                                 delegate:nil 
                                                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil ];
                                           [alertView show];
                                           [alertView release];
                                       }

                                   }];
```

Comment: Hi Surender Rathore,
Thanks....I want to implement checkin and post it on facebook and twitter

Comment: There is one method to add checkin in Foursquare.m file, method name is createCheckinAtVenue...